# How to make `column -t` ignore lines with specific characteristics?

Tags: text-formatting

I just thought how neat it would be to pipe my `/etc/fstab` through `column -te` to get a nicely formatted table.
But `column` of course has no way to discern comment lines and mountpoint definitions, so the comments are also split at every whitespace and formatted into table columns:

```
#                                          /etc/fstab:                  static   file                                      system     information.
#
#                                          Use                          'blkid'  to                                        print      the           universally   unique      identifier  for       a
#                                          device;                      this     may                                       be         used          with          UUID=       as          a         more  robust     way  to  name  devices
#                                          that                         works    even                                      if         disks         are           added       and         removed.  See   fstab(5).
#
#                                          <file                        system>  <mount                                    point>     <type>        <options>     <dump>      <pass>

#                                          /                            was      on                                        /dev/sda2  during        installation
UUID=8fa99d69-8dac-4aca-bb61-90f753ba5169  /                            btrfs    defaults,subvol=@rootfs,metadata_ratio=6  0          1
#                                          /home                        was      on                                        /dev/sda2  during        installation
UUID=8fa99d69-8dac-4aca-bb61-90f753ba5169  /home                        btrfs    defaults,subvol=@home                     0          2
```

Is there a way to make `column` only format lines that don't start with a `#`?

---

Edit: It seems I need to clarify that the example above is in fact a valid `fstab`. Btrfs has [subvolumes](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/SysadminGuide#Subvolumes) that can be mounted separately with the `subvol` and `subvolid` mount options.
That also means that the devices in the first column of the `fstab` are not necessarily unique.

Comment: How about just removing comments before feeding to column? Do you need comment lines?

Comment: They're there for a reason… (Well, not necessarily the ones I posted in the example, but my full fstab has a bunch of sensible comments.)

Comment: Pity, looks like my favourite solution was just deleted… For the record: `sort -k 1,1 -t $'\002' <(nl -nrz  -s $'\002' /etc/fstab | grep -v $'\002#' | column -t) <(nl -nrz  -s $'\002' /etc/fstab | grep $'\002#') | cut -d $'\002' -f 2`

Comment: Just noticed it was removing blank lines. That's easy to fix, though — just add `-ba` to the `nl` invocations: `sort -k 1,1 -t $'\002' <(nl -ba -nrz  -s $'\002' /etc/fstab | grep -v $'\002#' | column -t) <(nl -ba -nrz  -s $'\002' /etc/fstab | grep $'\002#') | cut -d $'\002' -f 2`

Answer (score 9):

I think the pragmatic solution will be to let `column` do its thing on the whole file, and then simply collapse any multiple spaces in the comment lines

```
column -t /etc/fstab | sed '/^#/ s/ \{1,\}/ /g'
```

Otherwise, I can't see any way to do it besides numbering the lines, processing the comment and non-comment lines separately, and then sticking it all back together, e.g.

```
sort -nk1,1 \
<(nl -nln /etc/fstab | grep -vE '^[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+#'| column -t | sed 's/ \{1,\}/\t/') \
<(nl -nln /etc/fstab | grep -E '^[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+#') \
| cut -f2-
```

Comment: Naturally, I didn't see your answer until I had posted mine.

Comment: This.  I strongly agree that the best approach is just to remove the extra spaces from comment lines.  Unless the comment lines contain non-collapsed whitespace to begin with - for example, to line up with text on other lines - this is definitely the approach that wins.  It's much, much simpler than every alternative.

Comment: This will probably become my go-to solution for this task because of its simplicity, but you should probably point out that it collapses any consecutive whitespaces in the comments.

Comment: Also don't forget to use `column -te` if you want to keep any blank lines in the file.

Comment: @n.st - `util-linux` `column` has no `-e` switch.

Comment: @don_crissti Curiously enough, the one from bsdmainutils 9.0.5 (on Ubuntu) does…

Comment: @n.st - well, different implementations - different switches... (e.g. the bsd version lacks the `-o` switch)

Comment: If commented words are longer than non-commented words, you'll end up with additional spaces with the first solution.

Answer (score 4):

With `sed` and `nl`:

```
nl -ba -nrz -s: /etc/fstab | \
sed '/^[[:digit:]]*:[[:blank:]]*\(#\|$\)/d;//!{s/\\/&&/g}' | \
column -t | sed 's|^0*\([[:digit:]]*\):\(.\)|\1c\\\
\2|' | sed -f - /etc/fstab
```

or with `sed` and `grep`:

```
grep -nvE '^[[:blank:]]*(#|$)' /etc/fstab | \
sed -E 's/\\/&&/g;s/^([[:digit:]])*:(.*)/\1c\\\
\2/' | column -t | sed -f - /etc/fstab
```

or shorter, with `sed` and `awk`:

```
awk '!/^[[:blank:]]*(#|$)/{print NR"c\\";gsub(/\\/,"&&");print}' \
/etc/fstab | column -t | sed -f - /etc/fstab
```

With a test file:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information
# <file system> <dir>   <type>  <options>   <dump>  <pass>

LABEL=ROOT    / ext4 noatime,discard 0 1
UUID=8fa99d69-8dac-4aca-bb61-90f753ba5169  / btrfs  defaults,subvol=@rootfs,metadata_ratio=6 0  1
# /home was on /dev/sda2  during installation
UUID=8fa99d69-8dac-4aca-bb61-90f753ba5169  /home btrfs  defaults,subvol=@home  0 2
LABEL=SWAP   none  swap sw,discard  0 0
UUID=7fa3-cb08  /media ext4 defaults 0 0
```

the output is:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information
# <file system> <dir>   <type>  <options>   <dump>  <pass>

LABEL=ROOT                                 /       ext4   noatime,discard                           0  1
UUID=8fa99d69-8dac-4aca-bb61-90f753ba5169  /       btrfs  defaults,subvol=@rootfs,metadata_ratio=6  0  1
# /home was on /dev/sda2  during installation
UUID=8fa99d69-8dac-4aca-bb61-90f753ba5169  /home   btrfs  defaults,subvol=@home                     0  2
LABEL=SWAP                                 none    swap   sw,discard                                0  0
UUID=7fa3-cb08                             /media  ext4   defaults                                  0  0
```

---

How these work:
The last `sed -f - /etc/fstab` modifies only the mount points definitions in `/etc/fstab` (leaving the other lines - including the empty ones - unchanged) using a script-`f`ile (`-` read from `stdin`) produced by the previous commands:

```
4c\
LABEL=ROOT                                 /       ext4   noatime,discard                           0  1
5c\
UUID=8fa99d69-8dac-4aca-bb61-90f753ba5169  /       btrfs  defaults,subvol=@rootfs,metadata_ratio=6  0  1
7c\
UUID=8fa99d69-8dac-4aca-bb61-90f753ba5169  /home   btrfs  defaults,subvol=@home                     0  2
8c\
LABEL=SWAP                                 none    swap   sw,discard                                0  0
9c\
UUID=7fa3-cb08                             /media  ext4   defaults                                  0  0
```

The first one uses `nl -ba -nrz -s:` to number all lines then

```
sed '/^[[:digit:]]*:[[:blank:]]*\(#\|$\)/d;//!{s/\\/&&/g}'
```

deletes lines that were originally commented or empty and escapes any backslashes in the remaining lines (not needed in this particular case, I know) the ouput is then piped to `column -t` so only the mount points definitions are columnated:

```
000004:LABEL=ROOT                                 /       ext4   noatime,discard                           0  1
000005:UUID=8fa99d69-8dac-4aca-bb61-90f753ba5169  /       btrfs  defaults,subvol=@rootfs,metadata_ratio=6  0  1
000007:UUID=8fa99d69-8dac-4aca-bb61-90f753ba5169  /home   btrfs  defaults,subvol=@home                     0  2
000008:LABEL=SWAP                                 none    swap   sw,discard                                0  0
000009:UUID=7fa3-cb08                             /media  ext4   defaults                                  0  0
```

this is further processed with

```
sed 's|^0*\([[:digit:]]*\):\(.\)|\1c\\\
\2|'
```

to produce the above mentioned script-file.
The second and third are similar (they produce the same output) so either

```
grep -nvE '^[[:blank:]]*(#|$)' | sed -E 's/\\/&&/g;s/^([[:digit:]])*:(.*)/\1c\\\
\2/'
```

or

```
awk '!/^[[:blank:]]*(#|$)/{print NR"c\\";gsub(/\\/,"&&");print}'
```

will match only mount points definitions, escape backslashes (if any), print the line number followed by `c\` and (on a separate line) the actual line content:

```
4c\
LABEL=ROOT    / ext4 noatime,discard 0 1
5c\
UUID=8fa99d69-8dac-4aca-bb61-90f753ba5169  / btrfs  defaults,subvol=@rootfs,metadata_ratio=6 0  1
7c\
UUID=8fa99d69-8dac-4aca-bb61-90f753ba5169  /home btrfs  defaults,subvol=@home  0 2
8c\
LABEL=SWAP   none  swap sw,discard  0 0
9c\
UUID=7fa3-cb08  /media ext4 defaults 0 0
```

which is then piped to `column -t` to produce the same script-file.

---

Another way with `ed` that does the same but reads the file only once:

```
ed -s <<IN <(nl -ba -nrz -s: /etc/fstab) | sort -t: -k1,1 | cut -d: -f2-
g/^[[:digit:]]*:[[:blank:]]*\(#\|$\)/p
g//d
,w !column -t
q
IN
```

The numbered lines are used as input to `ed`, the first sub-command `p`rints all the lines (`g`) that were originally commented or empty, the second one `d`eletes them and then the remaining lines are passed as input (`w`) to the shell (`!`) command `column -t`. The entire output is `sort`ed and `cut` removes the leading numbers.

Comment: I didn't even specifically think about that when pruning my `fstab` to get the example in the question, but it's already a minimal non-working example for your first approach, since it shows how even non-comment lines can start with identical first columns.

Comment: +1.  Two solutions for the price of one.  BTW, in the first one (the `sed` answer), I believe that you can leave out the `\(.\)` and the `\2`.  (Also, you can use `/` as the delimiter for the `s` command.)

Comment: @Scott - thanks. I usually stick with `|` as a delimiter when I have  slashes/backslashes in the expression so as to avoid the picket fence. The `1c\ ` part works (with my `gnu sed`) without the second backreference, true... but I don't think it works with all other `sed`s so I'll leave it as is.

Answer (score 3):

The suggestion “How about just removing comments before feeding to `column`?”
is not totally without merit.

```
#!/bin/sh
nl -ba /etc/fstab | sed "s/^ *//; s/\t/ /" > file0
grep    "^[0-9][0-9]* #" file0 > file1
grep -v "^[0-9][0-9]* #" file0 > file2
(cat file1; column -t file2) | sort -n | sed "s/^[0-9][0-9]* *//"
```

`nl –ba` numbers each line; the format is, effectively, `%6d\t`;
i.e., a number with leading spaces followed by a tab. 
`sed "s/^ *//; s/\t/ /"` strips the leading spaces
and replaces the tab with a space,
making it look more like what `column` output looks like. 
The `grep` commands break `file0` into `file1`, the lines with comments,
and `file2`, the lines without comments. 
(`XX*`
means *`X`* followed by zero or more `X`s;
in other words; one or more `X`s. 
This is the “poor man’s version” of `X+`;
i.e., a way of saying one or more `X`s
in a portable/universal way.) 
Each file retains the line numbers *from the original `/etc/fstab` file*.

`(cat file1; column -t file2)` runs the non-comment lines through `column –t`,
concatenating the result to the commented lines
(whose horizontal spacing is not modified). 
Then `sort –n` puts the lines back into their original order,
and `sed "s/^[0-9][0-9]* *//"` strips off the line numbers.

Output:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>

# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=8fa99d69-8dac-4aca-bb61-90f753ba5169  /      btrfs  defaults,subvol=@rootfs,metadata_ratio=6  0  1
# /home was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=8fa99d69-8dac-4aca-bb61-90f753ba5169  /home  btrfs  defaults,subvol=@home                     0  2
```

Note that this supports blank lines and comment lines with embedded white space
(i.e., embedded tabs or strings of two or more spaces) but not indented lines
(i.e., *leading* tabs or spaces).

If you want to harden this script a little
(i.e., make it more of a production version), you could

- Replace the temporary files with `/tmp` files
  with randomly (`mktemp`) generated names.
- Delete the temporary files upon completion.
- Change to use `[0-9]+` where appropriate
  (this might not be applicable to you if you have too old a system;
  e.g., Solaris, AIX, or anything without GNU tools).
- Dispense with `file1` and `file2` and compress the last line to something like

  ```
  (grep "^[0-9][0-9]* #" file0; grep -v "^[0-9][0-9]* #" file0 | column -t) | …
  ```

  But I believe it’s better to take a couple of extra lines and be clearer.
- Add support for indented lines.

Comment: Upvoting for the nice explanation

Comment: Too bad the person who downvoted me didn't provide an explanation, nice or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I had another usecase - using `column` on a CSV file with some comments. In this case, the option

`--table-noextreme columns`

has solved the issue for me.

```
-E, --table-noextreme columns
    Specify columns where is possible to ignore unusually long (longer than average)
    cells when calculate column width. The option has impact to the width calculation
    and table formatting, but the printed text is not affected.
```

Comparing output with and without `--table-noextreme 1`. Notice the width of the first column:

```
$column -s, -t all_statistics.csv
# Number of input log files 2 and maximum length of data list 2                                                                                             
# File#0: iteration_1_statistics.csv                                                                                                                        
# File#1: iteration_2_statistics.csv                                                                                                                        
# Memory bandwidth in MB/s                                                                                                                                  
Name                                                                       Block Size (B)  Min       Q1        Median    Q3        Max       N    File#1    File#2
Sequential write bypassing cache (128-bit)                                 256             5465.2    6586.8    7708.4    8830.0    9951.6    2.0  5465.2    9951.6
Sequential write bypassing cache (128-bit)                                 512             8885.9    11176.9   13468.0   15759.0   18050.0   2.0  8885.9    18050.0
Sequential write bypassing cache (128-bit)                                 768             13298.1   16639.3   19980.5   23321.8   26663.0   2.0  13298.1   26663.0
Sequential write bypassing cache (128-bit)                                 1024            16681.8   20844.0   25006.3   29168.6   33330.8   2.0  16681.8   33330.8
```

Using `--table-noextreme 1` to avoid column 1 being too wide:

```
$column -s, -t --table-noextreme 1 all_statistics.csv
# Number of input log files 2 and maximum length of data list 2
# File#0: iteration_1_statistics.csv                                                                                         
# File#1: iteration_2_statistics.csv                                                                                         
# Memory bandwidth in MB/s                                                                                                   
Name                                        Block Size (B)  Min       Q1        Median    Q3        Max       N    File#1    File#2
Sequential write bypassing cache (128-bit)  256             5465.2    6586.8    7708.4    8830.0    9951.6    2.0  5465.2    9951.6
Sequential write bypassing cache (128-bit)  512             8885.9    11176.9   13468.0   15759.0   18050.0   2.0  8885.9    18050.0
Sequential write bypassing cache (128-bit)  768             13298.1   16639.3   19980.5   23321.8   26663.0   2.0  13298.1   26663.0
Sequential write bypassing cache (128-bit)  1024            16681.8   20844.0   25006.3   29168.6   33330.8   2.0  16681.8   33330.8
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it with column alone.. writing a trivial script to do it is not too difficult.

Edit: This may work and it is little shorter. I tried it on the original example above, although it had already been put through column.  I did notice that this will remove empty lines so if that is a concern it may still need some polishing.

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUTFILE="${1}"

IFS=$'\r\n' GLOBIGNORE='*';
COMMENTS=(`grep -n ^# "${INPUTFILE}"`) 
ENTRIES=(`grep -n -v ^# "${INPUTFILE}" | column -t`)
TMPTAB=(`printf "%s\n" ${ENTRIES[@]} && printf "%s\n" ${COMMENTS[@]}`)

NEWTAB=(`printf "%s\n" ${TMPTAB[@]} | sort -n -t: -k1 | sed 's/^[0-9]\+://'`)
printf "%s\n" ${NEWTAB[@]}
```

I'll leave my original answer here but as @scott pointed out it doesn't work for some valid fstabs.

```
#!/bin/bash 

# columnize the non-comment lines
TABS=`grep -v ^# /etc/fstab | column -te`

# read the original fstab
while read LINE
 do 
  echo "${LINE}" | grep ^# > /dev/null 

  # if it is a comment line just write it in
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]
  then
       echo "${LINE}" >> new.fstab
  else
    # otherwise get the matching entry from the columnized fstab 
    ENTRY=`echo "${LINE}" | awk '{ print $1 }'`
    echo "${TABS}" | grep ^"${ENTRY}" >> new.fstab
  fi
 done < /etc/fstab
```

Comment: This assumes that no non-comment line begins with the first word of another (non-comment) line.  You would have discovered this if you had tested your script on the file presented in the question.  And, while that is an artificial, invalid example, it is possible on some systems that `/etc/fstab` will have a line for `/dev/disk1`, and then also line(s) for `/dev/disk10`, `/dev/disk11`, etc.  Your script will fail on such a file.  … … … … …  Also, as noted above, some versions of `column` don't support the `-e` option.

Comment: And, as a bit of general advice, you might want to avoid hard-coding output filenames (e.g., `new.fstab`) into scripts.  Just write to standard output, and let the user redirect it if he wants to.

Comment: @Scott What makes you think my example `fstab` would be invalid?

Comment: @n.st The fact that you have multiple entries for the same UUID.

Comment: @Scott - You're right I should have tested on the actual fstab presented.  I was only demonstrating that it could be done with a short script.  I did not intend for it to be a universal solution only an example.  Also, changing the grep to grep -w for the entry should take care of the matching of /dev/disk1 with /dev/disk10 and 11.  The fact that the first column may not be unique does mean this solution won't work in this case.

Comment: Full disclosure: I just learned a little something about btrfs, and, apparently, when using btrfs, it's perfectly valid to have multiple lines with the same UUID (i.e., the same value in the first column) so long as there are different `subvol=` options.  So, @CodyStevens, can you fix your answer to handle that?

Answer (score -2):

As suggested, ditch the comments ?

```
grep -v "^#" /etc/fstab | column -te
```

Comment: They're there for a reason… (Well, not necessarily the ones I posted in the example, but my full `fstab` has a bunch of sensible comments.)